# print out object array based on level

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to print out a list formatted by level. What I have is an array of objects.

Each object has a level eg 0, 1, 2. 0 being the uppermost and 2 being the innermost level. I want to print out the list with a indentation to each inner level

So a list would look like this

```
0
    1
    1
         2
         2
```

What my code looks like:

```
for (let category of json.categories) {
  if ((category.level = 0)) {
    console.log(
      category.category + "https://www.example.com/" + category.seo_name
    );
  }

  else if ((category.level = 1)) {
    console.log(
      "   " +
        category.category +
        " " +
        "https://www.example.com/" +
        category.seo_name
    );
  }

 else if ((category.level = 2)) {
    console.log(
      "     " +
        category.category +
        " " +
        "https://www.example.com/" +
        category.seo_name
    );
  }
}
```

This does look clunky and even worse, it doesn't work and there is no indentation.

Object example:

```
const json = {
  categories: [
    {
      category_id: "198",
      category: "Appliances",
      seo_name: "appliances",
      level:0
    },
    {
      category_id: "184",
      category: "Industrial Appliances",
      seo_name: "industrial-appliances",
      level:1
    },
  ],
  params: {
    visible: false,
    sort_order: "asc",
  },
};
```

Comment: you want to print in like that in console.log?

Comment: The conditions inside ifs should have == . A single = does validation on bits, not on the value you need

Comment: Once you have the level information use `value.toString().padStart(n*level, " ")` where `n` is a cofficient to make it as wide as you wish.

Comment: why not show us your OBJECT (it is not JSON if it is not a string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var data = [{ level: 0 }, { level: 1 }, { level: 1 }, { level: 2 }, { level: 2 }];

for (let obj of data) {
  let result = "";
  result = ' '.repeat(obj.level * 4) + obj.level;
  console.log(result)
}
```

If you want one line.

```js
var data = [{ level: 0 }, { level: 1 }, { level: 1 }, { level: 2 }, { level: 2 }];

data.forEach(obj => console.log(' '.repeat(obj.level * 4) + obj.level))
```

Comment: Thanks! The first option seems inefficient (still works) since you are initializing a string each time but the second one is so much cleaner and intuitive!

Answer (score 1):

How about using PRE and use the level to space it like suggested in a comment

```js
const obj = { categories: [ { category_id: "198", category: "Appliances", seo_name: "appliances", level:0 }, { category_id: "184", category: "Industrial Appliances", seo_name: "industrial-appliances", level:1 }, { category_id: "187", category: "Appliances", seo_name: "appliances", level:2 }, ], params: { visible: false, sort_order: "asc", }, };

const container = document.querySelector('pre');
container.innerHTML = obj.categories
  .map(({level,category,seo_name}) => `${"".padStart(level,"\t")}${category} https://www.example.com/${seo_name}`)
  .join("\n")
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: If you posted YOUR object, then I could look.

Comment: Please give an example of category object

Comment: Edited question.

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: I renamed the json to obj since JSON is a string and not an object - I also added a level 2

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning value inside your `if` condition using `=` instead of `==`. Also, a much cleaner way is by using `switch` instead of `if` (atlease in this case and in my opinion), and use some loop so that you can easily change the number of spaces you can leave in your indentation anytime instead of counting it manually as you have in your code.

```js
var data = [{ level: 0 }, { level: 1 }, { level: 1 }, { level: 2 }, { level: 2 }];

for (let element of data) {
  let result = "";
  switch (element.level) {
    case 1:
      for (let index = 0; index < 4; index++)
        result += " ";
      result += element.level;
      break;
    case 2:
      for (let index = 0; index < 8; index++)
        result += " ";
      result += element.level;
      break;
    default:
      result += element.level;
  }
  console.log(result)
}
```